# Java - getting selected text outside current program window

Tags: java, event-handling

Lets say i'm reading PDF file or using web broswer and i hilighted a word.

I want a procedure in JAVA , ***procedure in an independent program*** , to **get** that selected text 
using my JAVA program.

Comment: Doing a D'n'D or copy/paste should be pretty easy.

Comment: @Andrew: yep, that's true. I had assumed that the OP wanted to do this via a hot-key, but my assumption could easily be wrong since the information he's given us about his problem is currently very limited. To the OP (original poster), please give us more details about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if the other program will be "active" and have focus, and that you are desiring to use Java in the background to capture the selected text, perhaps using a hotkey combination.

Java may not be the best tool for this sort of behavior. Since Java is built to be as OS-agnostic as possible, it is difficult to do OS-specific tasks with Java. Having said this, this *can* be done with Java but would involve "stretching" Java and using non-Java code integrated with Java via JNI, JNA, or a OS-specific utility bridge such as AutoIt V3 if this is for a Windows platform. This solution would of course be OS-specific and could not be used in a cross-platform fashion.

---

**Edit 1**
You state in a comment:

> Thank you .. But how to use JNI OR JNA to do that ?

@blackgh: and therein lies the rub. You need to first learn JNI (more difficult if you're not already familiar with C or C++) or JNA (which in my opinion is easier), and then learn to make a keyboard hook if you want to make a hot key. This would take a bit of time and effort to do, but is doable. If this were my project, and I needed to do it quick and it absolutely had to integrate with Java, and if it were for a Windows platform, I'd go with AutoIt V3 or something similar to create a script for the hot key as the easiest solution, and in fact I've done something like this, but again you'd need to learn the the AutoIt language (it's like Basic).

Comment: Thank you ..
But how to use JNI OR JNA to do that ?

Comment: @blackgh: glad you understand, but also, please read Andrew's comment and my reply to it. I may be making assumptions that are making your problem more difficult than it needs to be. Also please be sure to tell more of the details of your problems in the initial post of any question you post here.